# git Merge specific directory from 2 unrelated repos with different paths to target directory

Tags: git, merge

Is it possible to merge a specific directory from 2 unrelated repos with different paths to
target directory.

repo1 is remote.  Target dir is at `~src/aaa/TARG`
repo2 is my local repo.  Target dir is at `~bbb/ccc/src/TARG`
I want to merge changes from repo1 `~src/aaa/TARG` onto repo2 `~bbb/ccc/src/TARG`
.

`TARG` is the target dir I want to update.  Changes have been made in `TARG` in both
repos so I expect I may have to resolve some conflicts.
I don't have examples that I have tried since I am still trying to figure out what
approach I should take.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "unrelated"?  They share no history in common?  You mention that "Changes have been made in `TARG` in both repos", which sounds like they _are_ related somehow?

Comment: I am scratching this effort to merge.   Another git expert with in my company said not possible to merge because of how our target source was created.  Thanks for your time.